# Is there a way to use previous row value in a dataframe to update the next row value of the dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I was working with a dataframe that looked somewhat as below:

| current | sold |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 6 |
| 10 | 8 |
| 15 | 10 |
| 20 | 12 |

My aim is to fins the available and remaining values. But my problem is that the values for the available and remaining column depends on the previous row value as below:

**remaining** **= max((available + current - sold),0)**

**available** **= remaining_prev + current - sold**

The final table is expected to look as follows:

| current | sold | available | remaining |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 6 | 0 | 0 |
| 10 | 8 | 2 | 4 |
| 15 | 10 | 9 | 14 |
| 20 | 12 | 22 | 30 |

Is there any way to achieve the same. I've been trying this for a couple of days. Method that doesn't require looping will be much appreciated.

Comment: Not only does it depend on the previous row but it depends on a different column of a previous row. I don't think this is doable without a loop.

Comment: Are you sure of the calculation? Can you break them down?

Comment: @mozway yeah. i've highlighted them

Comment: @IşıkKaplan was thinking the same. Thanks btw!!

Comment: @pseudosin I meant provide a numerical example. The issue is that we don't know the starting value

Comment: Where is the column `remaining_prev`?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df['remaining'] = np.maximum(df['current'] - df['sold'], 0)
df['available'] = (df['remaining'] * 2).cumsum()
df['remaining'] = df['available'] - df['remaining']

df

 current  sold  remaining  available
0        5     6          0          0
1       10     8          2          4
2       15    10          9         14
3       20    12         22         30
```

Answer (score 0):

You calculation don't really make sense to me in terms of the meaning of "available" and "remaining" (is it a stock?). Your formula is equivalent to counting 2 times what I would consider a real "remaining/available" stock.

Nevertheless, mathematically, you could convert:

```
remaining = max((available + current - sold),0)
available = remaining_prev + current - sold
```

to:

```
remaining = remaining_prev + 2*max(current - sold, 0)
```

This gives:

```
s = df['current'].sub(df['sold']).clip(0)
df['remaining'] = s.mul(2).cumsum()
df['available'] = df['remaining'].shift(fill_value=0)+s
```

output:

```
   current  sold  remaining  available
0        5     6          0          0
1       10     8          4          2
2       15    10         14          9
3       20    12         30         22
```